# CoreData concurrency - do I need a separate NSOperationQueue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, concurrency

I have a CoreData app in which I have two `NSNanagedContext`:s for concurrency. One for the main thread and one for my background thread.

In one of my view controllers I also have a separate `NSOperationQueue`, which I use like this:

```
[self.queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    [self processDataFromDictionary:jsonObject];
    [...]
```

I've noticed that my NSNanagedContext also have a perform block method. If I instead wrote:

```
 [self.backgroundContext performBlock:^{
    [self processDataFromDictionary:jsonObject];
```

Would that also be executed asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your managed object context is created using appropriate [concurrency type](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/initWithConcurrencyType%3a), calling performBlock from any other queue will cause the block to be executed asynchronously on the context's own queue.

Comment: Ok, thanks! So the other queue is needed to make it asynchronously then?

Comment: Something like that. [Here's a decent tutorial](http://volonbolon.net/post/26899408713/concurrency-with-core-data-on-ios-5) on the patterns you can adopt using the concurrency APIs added in iOS 5.